# If one checkbox is checked, end function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement, return

I have a div with the id "PCsetup" set to slide open when any of three check-boxes (#PCOF, #PCTMI, or #PCRM) are checked, but if one or two of the three is already checked, and the user checks another check-box, I want to end the function before it slides open, as it would actually close the "PCsetup" div.  How can I have the function check if the other two check-boxes are checked, and if they aren't, have the div slide down?  Here's what I have so far:

```
$(function() {
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function(){
    if ($("#PCOF").is(':checked'))|| ($("#PCRM").is(':checked')) {
       return;
    } else if $('#PCTMI').is(':checked')){
        $("#PCsetup").slideDown("slow");
    } else { 
        $("#PCsetup").slideUp("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you make what you have on jsFiddle.net ?

Comment: That code is not syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things: 1. The anonymous function in your example isn't closed, so the code isn't valid. 2. I had a hard time following exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but it sounds like you want to show the div if any combination of checkboxes are checked and hide it if none are checked. This will get you that result:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('#PCOF, #PCTMI, #PCRM').on('click', function() {
      var numChecked = $('#PCOF:checked, #PCTMI:checked, #PCRM:checked').length;

      if (!numChecked) {
        $('#PCsetup:visible').slideUp('slow');
      } else {
        $('#PCsetup').slideDown('slow');
      }   
    });
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/IsutuhI/3

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
$(function() {
    var $chks = $('#PCOF, #PCRM, #PCTMI');
    $chks.on('click', function(){
        var checked = $chks.filter(':checked').length > 0, visible = $("#PCsetup").is(':visible');
        console.log('dd', checked, visible)

        if (checked && !visible) {
            $("#PCsetup").finish().slideDown("slow");
        } else if(!checked && visible){
            $("#PCsetup").finish().slideUp("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5S6LD/)